# How to install tun/tap driver for openvpn on centos linux?

Tags: linux, centos, openvpn, drivers

How to install tun/tap driver for openvpn on centos linux?

Best wishes for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TUN/TAP driver is already part of the standard kernel image. Just run `modprobe tun` to load it.

If you are inside a virtual server (e. g. OpenVZ/Virtuozzo, Linux-Vserver et al) the provider needs to enable tun/tap-functionality first since you cannot load kernel modules yourself in these environments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, A great answer, I did but still same issue having...

Answer (score 2):

The standard kernel image has TUN/TAP driver configured as default. But if you want to check that with your running kernel you can:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`
$ sudo make menuconfig
```

After searching for "TUN" you will find:

```
Symbol: TUN[=m]
│ Prompt: Universal TUN/TAP device driver support
│   Defined at drivers/net/Kconfig:112
│   Depends on: NETDEVICES
│   Location:
│     -> Device Drivers
│       -> Network device support (NETDEVICES [=y])
│   Selects: CRC32
```

The kernel module is located at:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko
```

You can repeat almost the same procedure with a kernel source to check if TUN driver is compiled as a module. Just replace the first two commands with:

```
$ tar xvjf linux-2.6.XX.X.tar.bz2 && cd linux-2.6.XX.X
```

and continue.

Best regards

Humber