# Hamachi 2 for CentOS 6.3 ham0 network interface missing

Tags: centos6, rpm, hamachi

I am trying to install Hamachi on CentOS 6.3 (64-bit), but the network interface never appears.  I installed from [the official Hamachi RPMs](https://secure.logmein.com/es/labs/):

```
sudo rpm -ihv logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.86-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Installation appears to succeed:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:logmein-hamachi        ########################################### [100%]
install_initd ok.
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachi[  OK  ]
```

I am able to use the Hamachi client to join networks, and I even see this new server in the network I joined in the peer list on other clients.  Connection is green, with a direction connection to all peers in the network.  However, I am unable to actually send any data over Hamachi.

The problem is that the network interface doesn't exist.  When I run `ifconfig`, I only see the usual interfaces.  `ham0` is not listed, like it is on my Ubuntu boxes.  No interface has my Hamachi IP address assigned.

I have tried forcing the reinstall of the RPM, restarting the daemon, and restarting the box.  How can I get the `ham0` interface to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the TUN/TAP driver was not enabled.  Running `modprobe tun` was unable to load it.

This server was a VPS hosted under OpenVZ.  As [suggested by another post](https://serverfault.com/a/91343/52951), I had my VPS host enable the TUN/TAP driver, restarted the Hamachi daemon, and all was well.